# Responsive image map with roll-overs / Image swap positioned outside of div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm running into an issue with an responsive image map & rollovers.  I am using Matt Stow's responsive image jquery plugin to make sure that coordinates are responsive. Once clicked, lightview is pulled up.  Those are working nicely.

The problem lies in the positioning of an image that is swapped when an area of the map is hovered over. The swapped image is positioned outside of the div and kicks all the content down on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x; if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
<style>
img[usemap] {
border: none;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
}
</style>
```

The element in the page looks like:

```
<article class="span10">
    <div role="main" class="main"> <img src="imgs/graphics/SLoaders_page_main.jpg" alt="Superloaders options" width="846" height="809" border="0" usemap="#options" />
      <map name="options">
        <area shape="rect" coords="702,715,828,764" href="index.php" alt="back to home">
        <area shape="rect" coords="27,294,173,340"/)"  href='lightview-3.0.8/lightview-3.0.8/example/lv_imgs/alc.jpg' alt='IntelliTruck System' class='lightview' onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image1','','imgs/graphics/glows/ecu.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" data-lightview-group='example' data-lightview-title="Automated Load Control" data-lightview-caption="This is some content on light view"/>
      </map>
    </div>
  </article>
  <script src="js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
});
</script>
```

I found [this article](http://www.andensolutions.com/blog/responsiveImagePaths) that explains how they offset margins. I'm just not familiar enough with js to make it work with what I'm doing.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the image id:

```
id = “Image1”
```

I assigned the tag to the logo image, in the top-left, rather than the image map.  After moving the id tag to the right place, and it seems to be working correctly.